# How do I compile SASS/Compass without getting conflicts each time?

Tags: deployment, sass, compass

If I store and compile my SASS files locally I get conflicts on the generated .css file each time that I have to save and recompile. Diffmerge seems to struggle with this and it's taking up a lot of my time.

Should I be compiling this server side instead and .gitignore the *.css files?

What am I missing in my dev process? Surely everyone can't be saving and recompiling each time? Is grunt normally used or something to make the process seamless?

Comment: Unless you're using the *compressed* output setting (which eliminates whitespace), I can't imagine why there would be any sort of conflicts arising from any tool that evaluates diffs.  Can you be more specific about the actual problem, rather than soliciting opinions about workflow?

Comment: @cimmanon yes, compressed is what I'll be using for deployment to the production environment, isn't that the idea with the compressed version?

Comment: Well yes, you want compressed mode when you deploy it, but you can't accurately diff it because it puts all of your code onto a single line.  Every time that file changes, it looks like the entire file has been modified.

Comment: Yes I understand that, that's my problem and that's why I asked this question. Are you saying that there's no way around this that you know of?

Comment: The problem is not with Sass (or Compass), if that's what you're asking.  This is why no one keeps compiled binaries in version control.

Comment: I'm not asking if the a problem is with Sass, I'm asking how this is normally deployed. I have auto-deploments, so I push to git, and whatever get's pushed to git get's deployed to the server. If I use compressed SASS (Like I should be) then I get a conflicts each time I change/merge branches and It's a pain.  Is there a way around this?